# Access dynamicalley generated css id from the angular

Tags: css, angularjs

[image]

**html (dynamically generated one using jquery)**

```
<div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 25px;">
```

Above html has been generated dynamically using jquery.So could you tell me how can I access above `id` using angular.B'cos I need to change the `height` of the above css to `0px` when it's loading within the `iframe`(I know how to handle the `iframe` part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it with any js after the page has loaded. You can test this with the js console.

**Answer :**

```
var obj = angular.element('#undefined-sticky-wrapper');
obj.css('cssText', 'height:0px !important;');
```

Comment: $('#undefined-sticky-wrapper').css("height", "0px");

Comment: I would have just made my answer a comment but I don't have the rep

Comment: this is jquery no ? I need to do it within angular controller.

Comment: @DaltonJames - Don't misuse the "Answer" then. If you don't have the reputation, then wait until you do (like we all had to)

Comment: Okay I won't do that anymore. But for the angular part I am not exactly sure when it could target the ID. ( Should I delete my answer so it doesn't show the question as answered? )

Comment: Thanks for the support.I hope now you can have enough rep :)